# How to fill plots on different resolution data in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, fill

I want to fill between 2 plots. It works when chart is in 1W mode, but the idea is to be able to use it in 1D or 4H but still see the plots and fill based on the 1W data, hence the resolution param. In these timeframes the fill disappears yet the plots remain.

```
//@version=4
study("SMA/EMA Ribbon", overlay=true, resolution="1W")

ribbon_period = input(20, "Period")

ema = ema(close, ribbon_period)
sma = sma(close, ribbon_period)

p1 = plot(ema, color= #53b987, title="EMA", transp = 50, linewidth = 1)
p2 = plot(sma, color= #eb4d5c, title="SMA", transp = 50, linewidth = 1)
fill(p1, p2, color = ema > sma ? #26d06a55 : #f3313d55)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below code:

I compared the output of your code above and the below and both give the same output values.

```
//@version=4
study("SMA/EMA Ribbon - StackOverflow", overlay=true)


src = close, 

res = input(title="Use Different Timeframe? Uncheck Box Above", type=input.resolution, defval="W")

ribbon_period = input(20, "Period")

ema = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, ema(src, ribbon_period))
sma = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, sma(src, ribbon_period))

//EMA Plots
p1 = plot(ema, title="W EMA 20", linewidth=1, color=#53b987, transp = 50)
p2 = plot(sma, title="W SMA 20", linewidth=1, color=#eb4d5c, transp = 50)

fill(p1, p2, color = ema > sma ? #26d06a55 : #f3313d55)
```

Comment: Thanks this works but it has a step effect rather than the smoothed look of the original.  I get that stepped may be technically more accurate, but the default using my original code is smoothed and I prefer it. Do you know how the smooth it?

Comment: I am also really curious to understand why it works?  I mean as I have read, the original is just a more recent short cut way to do the same as you presented so I don't get why the results would be different (both about fill not working and about it being smoothed automatically).